# failed to install grub Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

During the Ubuntu 12.0.4 installation I have a `failed to grub-install` error. Attemp to boot from HDD failed. I'm read a numerous topics about grub installation failed error. I'm boot from Live CD and I'm trying to execute in terminal the command `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo fdisk /dev/sda`. I have the following `fdisk: unable to seek on /dev/sda: Invalid argument`. I'm execute `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`. Now I have

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbbc6bbc6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1              63   976751999   488375968+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Further I'm execute `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/ubuntu` and  `mount: /dev/sdb1 is not a block device` is displayed. I've `/boot/grub` non-empty directory on my local drive after ubuntu installation, but I don't understand how to fix this problem and correctly load installed ubuntu from `HDD`.

Comment: do you have dual-boot with windows ? or a hidden partition on your harddisk ? apparently you have forgotten to create a partition-table with gparted before first installation ? sometimes I am stupid too ...  ;-) http://stillstup.blogspot.de/2008/07/supergrub-makes-grub-supertool.html

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried ? not clear - whether you tried to install into sda or into sdb ?
Please read this to end, before you type anything ... :

Did you type:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sdb1 ?

or

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda ?

( this should be the correct one, in case that sda
is really a harddisk and not cd/dvd-drive ... )

or

> sudo grub-install /dev/sdb ?

This would be only right, if sda have not been tried before already - but sdb
would need a boot-flag too ! A boot-flag in sdb - with removed boot-flag in sda - you can settle these boot-flags with gparted after you did

> sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
>
> sudo update-grub

Then reboot ... so grub would then simply "jump over" sda.

This solution is not entirely "clean", but I don't know if sda has a partition-table ?!
In this case I would leave partition-table of sda simply out !

Comment: It doesn't work. The `/usr/bin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device /boot/grub (is /dev mounted)` caused by executing `sudo grub-install /dev/****`. After `sudo update-grub` execution I have `/usr/bin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device / (is /dev mounted)`